# Drupal 6 adding iframe tag to content editor?

Tags: drupal

hi how would I added the iframe tag to the content editor? I have the input format set to Full HTML but still it does not allow the iframe tag.

Answer (score 1):

Goto admin >> input formats, and add the iframe tag to Full HTML filter you're using for pages. That should do it.

**To Clarify:**
If in your list of filters you have "HTML Filter" Checked then you can manage the list of HTML tags.

However if you do not then you will need to check the filter on the wysiwyg editor you are using, so go to the config for they wysiwyg editor section you have installed.

Comment: thats what I thought too, but apparently you can not add tags to the FULL HTML Filter

Answer (score 0):

In this link: http://web.maetschl.com/node/14

I use a iframe.. with full html, and works

```
<iframe src="http://web.example" width=700 height=700>
```

Comment: are you using version 6? I'm using a node for a blog and it keeps showing the html coding when I preview.